# Double inheritance :

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

My questions are related to the following structure :
[image]

The abstract levels are just here to provide the member function for the "real" classes (D1 and D2). As it needs to be highly optimized, there is no virtuality (the destructors of the abstract levels are protected). Is the part with B0-C1-C2-D1 perfectly ok in the following cases :

1. B0, C1 and C2 have members function with different names ?
2. C1 and C2 have a function with the same name (for example `myFunction`) ?
3. C1 and C2 and D1 have a function with the same name (for example `myFunction`) ?
4. B0 and C2 have a function with the same name but not C1 (for example `myFunction`) ?

In each case what version of the function will be called by D1 ?

EDIT : a quick piece of code to illustrate that :

```
template<class CRTP> class A0
{
    public:
        void myfunction1();
    protected:
        ~A0();
        double mymember;
};

template<class CRTP> class B0 : public A0<CRTP>
{
    public:
        void myfunction2();
    protected:
        ~B0();
};

template<class CRTP> class C1 : public B0<CRTP>
{
    public:
        void myfunction3();
    protected:
        ~C1();
};

template<class CRTP> class C2 : public B0<CRTP>
{
    public:
        void myfunction4();
    protected:
        ~C2();
};

class D1 : public C1<D1>, public C2<D1>
{
    public:
        void myfunction5();
};
```

Comment: There's no `D0` in your picture. It's clear that *other* people will be confused by such a design, but it looks like you even got *yourself* confused! :-)

Comment: Thanks. Edited : D0 and D1 -> D1 and D2

Comment: The drawing is nice, but it hardly as useful as code. In particular, it seems that all the way to the `C` level there are only templates with CRTP, right?

Comment: Yes. They are like A0<CRTP>, B0<CRTP> : public A0<CRTP>, C1<CRTP> : public B0<CRTP>, D1 : public C1<D1>, public C2<D1>

Comment: Note: you have two copies of `B0` in `D1`, one through `C1` and one through `C2`, is this intended ? (aka Diamond Inheritance).

Comment: You should avoid diamonds in inheritance trees.

Comment: I'd tentatively say that if you're going to be highly optimizing anything, you shouldn't be using 4 levels of inheritence.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: I have the feeling that there are no diamonds there, as the bases are templates applied to the derived type, but Vincent has decided that he does not want to produce the actual code to verify this. (If my believe is correct, `C1` inherits from `B0<C1>`, and `C2` inherits from `B0<C2>` --i.e. different bases). But that is the problem with hiding the code from the answer (-1 from me now)

Comment: Oh.  Okay then.  Well, good luck with that.

Comment: @Wug : I thought that there was no problem with large inheritancy trees without any virtuality but maybe I'm wrong (can you confirm this) ?

Comment: If you don't have any virtuality, why do you have 4 levels?  It seems like an abuse of OO paradigms to me.

Comment: @Wug : the only reason I do that it's because the abstract classes have many many functions (~100 each). But what is the cost of inheritance without virtuality at runtime ?

Comment: If you have classes with 100's of functions, you have another problem.

Comment: @Wug : I've just tested a small code with an inheritance tree generated by template (100 levels...), each level having a templated math function that needs severals copies VS an equivalent class with no inheritance and ... I measured no performance overhead due to inheritance. With the use of virtuality and polymorphism the overhead is about 1/3 (which is huge from my point of view) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not say it's ok, unless you are ok with having `A0` and `B0` twice in your class, although they are different classes (`B0<C1>` and `B0<C2>`). Unless you are doing some specialization this is most likely [not what you want](http://ideone.com/12qdv).

A possible solution to this would be [something like this](http://ideone.com/6ZBMa), which removes the multiple inheritance:

```
template<class CRTP, class Base = B0<CRTP> > class C1 : public Base
{
    public:
        void myfunction3();
    protected:
        ~C1();
};

template<class CRTP, class Base = B0<CRTP> > class C2 : public Base
{
    public:
        void myfunction4();
    protected:
        ~C2();
};

class D1 : public C2<D1,C1<D1>>
{
    public:
        void myfunction5();
};
```

So, what if you do want to have that diamond in there, can you do it without multiple base class instances? 
No, because 
a) as I said the base classes are different and 
b) in C++ virtual inheritance only works with classes that have a vtable.

Answer (score 0):

"Perfectly Ok" is somewhat subjective, but all of the situations are well-defined within the language.

You'll probably run into issues with [diamond inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-diamond.html) in `D1`.  *If it's appropriate*, you can use [virtual inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-where.html) to have `C1` and `C2` to inherit from a common base.  It isn't always appropriate, hard for us to guess.

1)

They are different classes with different methods, no conflict.

2)

There are no problems within `C1` or `C2`, though `D1` will have problems.

3)

You'll *have* to define it in `D1`.  Inherited `myFunction` calls will be shadowed (inaccessible) from the outside.  You can call them from within D1 like so:

```
struct D1 {
  void myFunction() {
    C1::myFunction();
    C2::myFunction();
  }
}
```

With CRTP this is going to be annoying to do.  I'd recommend using typedefs in the class definitions to keep what's left of your sanity.

4)

`C1` will have whatever functions that `B0` gives it.  If they are inaccessible, then you'll get a compiler error if you reference them.

I'd recommend against this design, honestly.  Break everything into small concrete objects and compose them.  Maintaining this won't be a project, it will be a career.